# PowerBI connection issue in Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi

I am trying to get data into excel from PowerBI.
Getting the below error :

[image: Screenshot]

Can someone help me with this issue ?

Thanks

I have tried sign-out & sign-in & have cleared cache